# Standard number of Network Interfaces on a Mac Mini

Tags: mac, ethernet, network-interface

Any insight into this would be very helpful to me.  I am using a Mac Mini 2011.  I ran `ifconfig` to see the network interfaces and see three ethernet cards.  Some are in promiscuous mode, although only one has an IP and is active.  However is this normal to see three ethernet interfaces and why would there by since there is only one ethernet interface?

Here is the output of ifconfig:

```
en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether c8:2a:14:55:db:05 
    inet6 fe80::18c3:d66:a0a0:bab9%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,energy-efficient-ethernet>)
    status: active
en1: flags=8823<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 28:cf:da:05:27:c1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr c8:2a:14:ff:fe:f6:23:86 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether b2:00:1f:62:38:61 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0a:cf:da:05:27:c1 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether b2:00:1f:62:38:61 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::668:7fa:43d9:908c%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Is this normal for a Mac?  For example I run ifconfig on a debian Linux machine and get:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::5830:9f0c:3d24:5a34  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:63:bb:a5:e2:f9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1949053  bytes 2903801237 (2.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 8  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1438197  bytes 102731272 (97.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8060  bytes 695724 (679.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8060  bytes 695724 (679.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 76:72:79:9a:ac:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. macOS uses `enX` for Ethernet, wireless Ethernet (802.11/Wi-Fi), and Thunderbolt networking interfaces.

On your 2011 Mac mini, `en0` is built-in Ethernet, `en1` is Wi-Fi, and `en2` is Thunderbolt.

Comment: If you know where I can look to answer questions like this about Mac OS in the future I would be happy to know the best link, source or book for understanding the Mac OS kernel.

Comment: @jonnyjandles Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach, by Amit Singh (ISBN 0321278542) was the bible when it came out. It's probably showing its age now, but since Apple doesn't bother to document low-level stuff like this, Singh's book is probably still the best source, other than Apple's Darwin open source codebase itself.